# Continues graph print like in Oscilloscope

Tags: raspbian

1. I am using raspberry pi 2 board with raspbian loaded.
2. Sampling analog sensor whose value I need to plot the graph of this like on oscilloscope.
3. Values keep on coming & I need to print it continuously.
4. How to do that.
5. I had used matplotlib, but in that only way to do is save samples & then plot (which I found), its not continuous.
6. Plotly is online, I don't have net access on my device.
7. currenly i am doing like this as in post#6 here:
   https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=115089

Comment: May be you can run two different programs or use threads. While one would be continuously capturing analog values as per your sampling rates, other will be plotting. You can use `nice` to make one prioritize. Hope it helps.